# How to pass an image to another form

Tags: c#, tcp, remote-desktop

I'm currently making an remote desktop viewer via TCP and I want to pass that image and show it in another form. In form2 the image appears as blank and the form stops working after some time.

Form1:

```
Form2 fm2 = new Form2();
int v = 0;
while(true){
//sendmessage to client
    while(true){
      stream = client.GetStream();
      BinaryFormatter as1 = new BinaryFormatter();
      pictureBox1.Image = (Image)as1.Deserialize(stream);
      fm2.dImage(image);
    if (v == 0) { fm2.Show(); v++; }
    }
}
```

Form 2:

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();


}
public void dImage(Image image) 
{
    this.pictureBox1.Image = image;
//pictureBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => pictureBox1.Image = image));
}
```

Client:

```
while (timerStart == true)
{   
    BinaryFormatter asd3 = new BinaryFormatter();
    asd3.Serialize(stream, comands.GrabDesktop());    
}
public static Image GrabDesktop()
{
    Rectangle bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
    Bitmap screenshot = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
    Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot);
    graphic.CopyFromScreen(bounds.X, bounds.Y, 0, 0, bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
    return screenshot;
}
```

Comment: You can try Image.FromStream(stream). How do you upload the image stream? What method you are using on the client?

Comment: Form 2 probably is closing.  See my 2 form project at following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: @OguzOzgul if I try in the same form it works. The problem is when I try to pass it to another form.

Comment: Where is that while loop running? In a background thread?

Comment: try this `pictureBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => pictureBox1.Image = image));`

Comment: @OguzOzgul It's an "await Task.Run" after connection is made.

Comment: Try pictureBox1.Invoke as in my last comment

Comment: @OguzOzgul System.InvalidOperationException "Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created" throws that exception if I put that code in form2

Comment: Oh yes, you haven't shown the form yet. When are you going to show the form?

Comment: Please post your full source code

Comment: public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            

        }
        public void dImage(Image image) 
        {
            pictureBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => pictureBox1.Image = image));
        }

Comment: @OguzOzgul Done, check the post updated.

Comment: When do you show Form2? In your source code, you never show it.

Comment: Where is fm2.Show() ?

Comment: @OguzOzgul full code is now updated

Comment: We need to see what's happening. This should work, but you have an infinite loop there, you may be doing something else which we can't see and is the root of the problem. Please post your full source code, form1.cs and form2.cs

Comment: I tried the same on simple form1 and form2 and it succeeded. That's why we need the full source code here.

Comment: I can't reach it. This web site is banned in my country. Never mind.